# Check for my code coverage ratio from my build process

Tags: unit-testing, code-coverage

I am using Visual Studio 2008 Code Coverage and I have many classes that are 100% covered by my unit tests. How could I check during my build process that these classes remain 100% covered by my unit tests (also executed during my build process after compilation) ?

Comment: This will depend on what you are using for continuous integration build.

Comment: Could you paste your msbuild script please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For [code coverage](http://www.ndepend.com/Features.aspx#Coverage) ratio check you can use NDepend.
You can declare an attribute, like **YourNamespace.FullCoveredAttribute**
and tag your classes 100% covered by tests.

```
using YourNamespace;
...
[FullCoveredAttribute]
class MyClassFullCovered { ... }
```

Then the single following CQL query will check for all classes 100% covered and warn if it finds any flaw:

```
WARN IF Count > 0 IN SELECT TYPES WHERE
HasAttribute "YourNamespace.FullCoveredAttribute" AND
PercentageCoverage < 100
```

The magic comes from the fact that NDepend can gather [code coverage metric from both NCover and VSTS Coverage](http://www.ndepend.com/Coverage.aspx).